# Understanding the general metric of a stationary spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, vector-fields

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_spacetime#Description_and_analysis) the metric for any stationary spacetime, when made independent of $t$, has the form

$ds^2 = \lambda(dt - \omega_i\ dy^i)^2 - \lambda^{-1}\ h_{ij}\ dy^i\ dy^j$

with the Killing vector $\xi$ being the unit $t$ vector, $\lambda$ its norm, and $h_{ij}$ the spatial metric.  And $\omega_i$ are the spatial components of the twist 4-vector $\omega_\mu = e_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\xi^{\nu}\nabla^{\rho}\xi^{\sigma}$, with $e$ the volume form.  I'm having trouble digesting what $\omega$ really is, and how that leads to the formula above.

My understanding is that the volume form applied to a *triplet* of vectors would give (the co-vector of) the vector orthogonal to them, whose magnitude is equal to their 3-volume.  But what does it mean to feed the volume form the combined covariant derivatives (gradient?) of the Killing vector?

I certainly understand that $g_{tt}$ should be $\lambda$ since $g(\hat e_t, \hat e_t) = g(\xi, \xi)$, but the rest of the metric I don't grasp.  I want to understand it more from a geometric perspective, but I'll take anything.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking for geometric intuition about the metric, with emphasis on the role of the $\omega_i\,dy^i$ term? Or are you asking specifically how to show that the equation $\omega_\mu=e_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\xi^\nu\nabla^\rho\xi^\sigma$ is consistent with the metric? Or are you asking how the metric is derived from this equation? (Or more generally, how to deduce a metric from information about its geodesics?)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Geometric intuition about the metric, with emphasis on the role of the $\omega_i\ dy^i$ term.  With a more precise geometric description of $\omega_{\mu}$ than "it measures how the Killing vector fails to be orthogonal to 3-space".  But if it's not too much to ask, I do also want to understand how to construct a metric from geodesic information.